# How to find invariant subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

If I have a multiplication operator $L_A: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$, where
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 43 & -32 & 35 & 14 \\ -66 & 44 & -52 & -18 \\ -137 & 97 & -110 & -41 \\ 59 & -43 & 48 & 18\end{pmatrix}
$$

how do I find a matrix $B$ whose row space is smallest $L_A$-invariant subspace that contains the vector $(0,2,1,2)$. Do I need to find the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors?

Comment: It is unusual that you are considering row space rather than column space. You haven't fully described the operator; is it $\mathrm{LA}(x) = Mx$ (where $x$ is a column vector) or $\mathrm{LA}(x) = xM$ (where $x$ is a row vector)?

Comment: The matrix is A.

Comment: I would guess the $L$ in $L_A$ stands for left multiplication by $A$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the map you have in mind is $L_A(x) = Ax$. If this is not what you have in mind, please edit you question to clarify what you do mean.

If $v$ is the column vector $v = (0,2,1,2)$, then the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{v & Av & A^2 v & A^3 v}
$$
has column span equal to the smallest $L_A$-invariant subspace containing $v$. Thus, $B = M^\top$ has the desired properties.

---

When following the above process, I end up with the answer
$$
B = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & -1 & -1 & 0\\2 & 0 & -2 & 12\\1 & 2 & -1 & 12\\2 & -2 & 1 & -3\end{matrix}\right).
$$
Unlike the answer that you found, this matrix has rank 3.

You can also row-reduce this matrix to find another possibility, namely
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 3\\0 & 1 & 0 & 3\\0 & 0 & 1 & -3\end{matrix}\right).
$$

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong, I got $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -64 & 88 & 194 & -86 \\ 1125 & 2704 & 12100 & 110592 \\ 5488 & -11664 & -137842 & 11664\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @asdfkasmfa If you are trying to follow my recommendation, you definitely are. The first row of $B$ should be $v$, but somehow you have the zero vector

Comment: Oh, is B supposed to be B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\ -64 & 88 & 194 & -86 \\ 1125 & 2704 & 12100 & 110592 \\ 5488 & -1164 & -137842 & 11664\end{pmatrix}

Comment: But the matrix is wrong for some reason.

Comment: What do you mean by “the matrix is wrong”?

Comment: Why would there be a single “correct answer”? There are many matrices that have the same row space. It sounds like there is some important context that you have left out

Comment: The question just states "consider the multiplication operator $L_A: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$, where 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 43 & -32 & 35 & 14 \\ -66 & 44 & -52 & -18 \\ -137 & 97 & -110 & -41 \\ 59 & -43 & 48 & 18\end{pmatrix}
$$
Find a matrix $B$ whose row space is smallest $L_A$-invariant subspace that contains the vector $(0,2,1,2)$."

Comment: @asdfkasmfa If the question says "find **a matrix**" with a given row space. It stands to reason that there are infinitely many correct answers. If you're trying to figure out how exactly a specific answer might have been derived, then you should ask a question about that and include what that specific answer was.

Comment: But I am not given the specific answer, but I can check if it is a correct answer, which in this case it is not. Did I make a calculation error?

Comment: Earlier you said "it is not *the* correct answer", which implies that there is one correct answer. I haven't checked your work so I'm not sure

Comment: Sorry, I meant a correct answer.

Comment: I'll check your work and get back to you

Comment: I've checked and you absolutely have some errors in your calculation. I'll edit my question to include my result.